# Pinterest Rich Pins Save : Truncating Title and tags

Tags: javascript, pinterest, og-meta

I am having strange issue in my rich pin save button. Its truncating title and tags while creating new PINs into Pinterest.

I have used same OG data given in pinterest developer site.
Reference : https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/articles/?

Any suggestion or help on this will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My code is as below.

```
    <head>

    <meta name="p:domain_verify" content="SITE_VERIFICATION_CODE"/>

    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="sample title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="sample content" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.sample.com/">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="sample site name" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://live.staticflickr.com/7027/6851755809_df5b2051c9_b.jpg"  data-dynamic="true">
    <meta property="article:tag" content="tag1,tag2"  >
    <meta property="article:published_time" content="2018-08-12T00:01:56+00:00" />
    <meta property="article:author" content="Sample author" />
    <meta property="og:keywords" content="keywords1,keywords2"  >

    <script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <a target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer;" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"
   data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"
   data-pin-custom="true">
   SHARE TO PINTEREST
   </a>
  </body>
```

Note : i have removed site verification code in above sample code.
Ref. https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/articals/?
Ref. https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/reference/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I consulted issue with Pinterest Team and got following feedback. I hope anyone who's having same issue or having same requirements will get benefit from this.

[image]

[image]